# Fake HTTP response with Frida

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, frida

An Android application sends a request to "https://google.com". How would i
fake the HTTP response without an actual network request, using Frida?
I am trying to teach myself reverse-engineering, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Faking a complete response is not that easy, first you have to look at the code that performs the requests and check what HTTP client is used, then get the HTTP clients documentation and understand how responses are created and then identify a method you can hook with frida.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing that is redirecting the request to an address that  you control and then return there a user-controlled response.

You will then need to find which methods to instrument related to the HTTP request itself and return valid data to the app.